# How to appendchild table to my cell and row

Tags: javascript

Hello I have some problem with my code .I have no clue how to `table.appendchild(row)`. I've try to do it with append or appendchild but is not working.

**My Code:**

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    
        body.appendChild(table);
        var createrow = function(c1,c2){
            var row = document.createElement('tr');
            row.appendChild(c1);
            row.setAttribute('class', 'row')
            row.appendChild(c2); 
        
            return row;
        }
        var createcell = function(value){
            var cell = document.createElement('td');
            cell.setAttribute('class', 'cell');
            cell.innerText=value;
            table.appendChild(cell);
            return cell;
        }
        
        
        body.appendChild(createrow(createcell('Ion'),createcell('24')))
        body.appendChild(createrow(createcell('Gigle'),createcell('26')))
```

Comment: Pelase explain the problem properly. I have tried, it is showing the table rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`target.appendChild(another)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) means "take this element "another" and place it as a child in the element "target".

You have made some mistakes in your code. First one is at your `createcell` function:

```
var createcell = function(value){
    var cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell.setAttribute('class', 'cell');
    cell.innerText=value;
    // table.appendChild(cell); -- uncommented
    return cell;
}
```

The purpose of this function is to create a "cell" for your table. You are doing that, but you are also doing `table.appendChild(cell);` which means that you are placing that cell in the table. That is not correct. I have uncommented it.

Yours `createrow` function seems correct.

Finally, you are doing

```
body.appendChild(createrow(createcell('Ion'),createcell('24')))
```

which means "take the result of the `createrow` function (which is your `<tr>` element) and put it in the element "body"". Your `body` is the `<body>` element. Not something you wanted to give your row to. You want to place the row in your table. So you need to correct that into

```
table.appendChild(createrow(createcell('Ion'),createcell('24')))
```

which means "create a row, and place it as child in the element "table"". Yours `table` is then the `<table>` element. Now the row is placed in the correct location.

Comment: Yes , it's working . Ty 4 this i will mark as correct answer ! i understend what i;ve do wrong !